# Configure Elastic4S 6.0 using http client to run on Play 2.5 with tests

Tags: scala, elastic4s

I'm in the process of updating my Play 2.5.14 application from Elastic4s 2.4 to Elastic4s 6.0. The application works (exlusively via the httpClient) and I can get my tests run but not both at the same time!

Exceprt  from My build.sbt

```
  "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s-core" % Versions.elastic4s excludeAll ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.logging.log4j"),
   // for the http client
  "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s-http" % Versions.elastic4s excludeAll ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.logging.log4j"),
  // for the tcp client
  "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s-tcp" % Versions.elastic4s excludeAll ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.logging.log4j"),
  // testing
  "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s-testkit" % Versions.elastic4s % "test",
  "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s-embedded" % Versions.elastic4s % "test",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.8.2" % "test",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.8.2" % "test",
```

My test class is  configured as follows

```
class ElasticsearchRepositorySpec extends WordSpec with SearchMatchers with 
ClassLocalNodeProvider with HttpElasticSugar {

val testClient = http
  // injections
val elasticClientProvider = new ElasticClientProvider {
override def client: HttpClient = testClient
}
```

the http object coming from the ClassLocalNodeProvider. I don't use the TcpClient at all but if I comment out elastic4s-tcp from the build.sbt (or set it to % test) the Local Node fails at startup with

```
uk.gov.ons.addressIndex.server.modules.ElasticsearchRepositorySpec *** ABORTED ***
  org.elasticsearch.transport.BindTransportException: Failed to bind to [9300-9400]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.bindToPort(TcpTransport.java:755)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.bindServer(TcpTransport.java:720)
```

But if I don't comment it out the application fails with

```
[error] p.c.s.n.PlayRequestHandler - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
        at io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.touch(ReferenceCountUtil.java:73)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.touch(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:107)
```

and it seems I may need to upgrade to play 2.6 to fix this, unless I can get my tests to work without the Tcp classes.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to configure the tests to work without the TcpClient, so ended up having to bite the bullet and upgrade to Play 2.6. This did indeed fix the problem.

Comment: The elastic netty version in the TCP client clashes with some play / spark versions. The testkit uses TCP as well, in 7.0.0 onwards TCP will be gone.